# Altering MySql Null and Default Properties

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following properties:

```
mysql> desc oc_product;
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| date_available    | date          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
```

I am interested in setting the property `Null` to `NO` and the `Default` to `0000-00-00`.

I have accomplished the `Default` -> `0000-00-00` part using:

`ALTER TABLE oc_product CHANGE date_available date_available date DEFAULT '0000-00-00';`

However, I am unable to change `Null` to `NO`.

I have tried the following queries:

`ALTER TABLE oc_product CHANGE date_available date_available date NULL NO;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some database, you can just specify wheter it can be null or not by adding `NULL` or `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE oc_product MODIFY COLUMN date_available NOT NULL;
```

But I believe in MySQL you need to specify the whole field type as well, so it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE oc_product MODIFY COLUMN date_available date NOT NULL;
```

And if you want to specify (or keep) the default value too, you need to add that as well. That's the issue with MySQL, you must specify the entire field definition as you want it, not just the changes.

```
ALTER TABLE oc_product MODIFY COLUMN date_available date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```

You can use MODIFY instead of CHANGE if you don't need to change the column name. Apart from that they are the same. The `ALTER TABLE` syntax and all its options are documented well, so you may have a look here:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html
```

Comment: I just tried this, and while it does change `Null` to `NO`, it seems to change the `Default` back to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

to change the default value, and also make it nullable

```
ALTER TABLE oc_product 
  CHANGE `date_available` `date_available` DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NULL;
```

Comment: I use `CHANGE` instead of `MODIFY` since thats what the GUI I use spits out (sqlYOG)